# How to make a reference from an Enum with constants to an Enum with cases of type String

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 enums.

First enum contains Constants:

```
enum Constants {

static let settings = "settings"
static let help = "Help"
}
```

Second Enum is of type String and contains few cases:

```
enum SettingsName: String {
    case Settings = "Settings"
    case Help = "Help"
}
```

How can I associate the String from the Constants enum to my second Enum ?
I've tried `case Settings = Constants.settings` but is not working.

Comment: You can define your constants as `static let settings = SettingsName.Settings.rawValue`, the other way won't work because a raw value for a case has to be a literal

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The raw value of a case must be a literal.

Comment: Then is any chance to remove the "red code" from my controller ?
I want my code to look clean and nice.

Comment: You can write `enum SettingsName: String { case Settings, Help }`, the raw value is equal to the case. However enum case are supposed to be named lowercased.

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu you can change color for Strings in Xcode preferences 